# Data Flow expression to split a string except for email address

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I wanted to write a DataFlow expression to split a string if it has ‘.’ Also ignore the split if it has email address

```
Eg: 
1) T.K Mike should be T K Mike
2) T.K. Mike should be T K Mike
3) Tkmike@abc.com.uk should be the same no splitting required
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below sample data:

[image]

I have taken above data as source in data flow, added derived column activity to the source and created a column with below expression:

```
iif(instr(<ColumnName>, '@')>0,<ColumnName>, regexReplace(regexReplace(<ColumnName>, "(?<=\\w)\\.(?=\\w)", " "), "\\.", " "))
```

Above expression has given the required output:

[image]